# MP4 HTML Video Embed Won't Work In Safari on iOS

Tags: html, ios, video, html5-video

Having such a strange issue, i have an mp4 embedded using html video element. It's linking directly to the mp4 file like so:

```
<video controls playsinline preload="metadata">
                                <source type="video/mp4" src="https://example.com/video.mp4#t=0.001">
                              </video>
```

It does sort of seem to happen sometimes and not others, but right now all I get on my iPhone iOS 14.6 and simulator iOS 15 is a video saying it's 0 seconds long. The same video plays fine in chrome, and it even plays fine in safari on my iMac, it's just the iPhone. This particular video is converted from WebM to mp4 with FFmpeg if that makes a difference somehow.

Also just as a side note, and another question: I want to show a preview of the video, but again on iOS using #t=0.001 doesn't actually work, it just shows a white frame, I'm assuming Apple changed things again and wondered if anyone has a new solution? - This happens obviously only when the video tag actually works.

It looks like there is something wrong with byte requests in safari on the iphone. Screenshot ...

[screenshot of errors in mobile safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxGgH.png)

**UPDATE**

I thought i had solved it by streaming the video with php, but it's not. This is a really intermittent issue. It seems to be find with short 10 second videos, but when they get anything like 30 seconds or above it starts to not stream it; but the video is fine, i can download the file and play it on my computer.

I am seeing this in the debug console in safari for the iphone:

```
Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load
```

What does this mean? It's driving me insane, all works fine in every other browser just not on iphone (not even chrome on the iphone works) so this must be something to do with iOS

Comment: Can you hare a link to the video - this will help to understand the problem?

Comment: could it be a CORS issue - is the video on another domain?